# SSO into community experience site from a custom third party IdP using JWT Token

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, jwt, digital-experience, oidc

I'm trying to setup SSO login for customers into one of our Salesforce digital experience sites. The IdP is a third party custom solution that generates a JWT token. SAML isn't currently an option.

I've looked into using the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow but I've read that is only for server to server authentication and not authorization.

I've also thought about using OIDC for only the relying Salesforce side, but not the IdP server side. It seems this won't work because SFDC is looking for state parameters that the IdP isn't passing.

The IdP is providing a user id, email address, and a role in the token. The JWT is formatted as Header,Payload,Signature (SHA256).

I've started looking into creating a Custom Authentication Provider Plugin using the Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass. But I'll be honest, the lack of JWT(or any) examples online makes me nervous that I'm headed down the wrong path.

Insight that I'm headed in the right direction, or if anyone knows of an easier way to achieve this, it would be appreciated.